# How to implement "Change Password" redirection in .Net MVC4?

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-4, filter, authorization, t4mvc

In *.Net MVC4* I'm using a subclassed [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to redirect all requests to the "Change Password" page when a user's password has been reset as follows:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Call base class method first
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        // Only redirect if password change is required and the requested action
        // is not "Change Password"
        if (!passwordChangeRequired
            && !(filterContext.Controller is ApplicantController &&
                 MVC.Applicant.ActionNames.ChangePassword.Equals(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName)))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller", MVC.Applicant.Name },
                    { "action", MVC.Applicant.ActionNames.ChangePassword }
                });
        }
    }
```

Have just written this code it seems to work but am not yet confident and wondering if it could be simplified.

Especially regarding controllers and actions - the project is using [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) so do both need to be included separately in the check and redirect or could they somehow be combined?

Also should the `base.OnAuthorization` call be made at the start or end (or neither)?

Grateful for any pointers...

Comment: your implementation looks good. But if you want simplicity, you could use standard `[Authorize]` attribute and set redirect destination in your web.config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up modifying this slightly to use [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead of [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

In case this is of use to anyone here is the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ChangePasswordAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Filter on executing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current action context</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        // Don't redirect to "Change Password" action if it is the current action
        if (filterContext.Controller is ApplicantController &&
            MVC.Applicant.ActionNames.ChangePassword.Equals(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Redirect if password change is required
        if ((filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKeys.PasswordChangeRequired] != null) 
            && (bool)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKeys.PasswordChangeRequired])
        {
            // Save route in session so the user can be redirected appropriately after a successful password change
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.RouteData.Values);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKeys.PasswordChangeRouteValues] = routeValues;

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller", MVC.Applicant.Name },
                    { "action", MVC.Applicant.ActionNames.ChangePassword }
                });
        }
    }
}
```